# Not able to copy jar to an absolute path

Tags: java, ant, jar, copy

I am trying to copy Demo.jar file (generated by an ant task) on my desktop(or any directory specified by it's absolute path on my XP machine).

I am specifying **absolute path** in a properties file and reading it on the fly.
The problem is I am not able to read this absolute path properly, where I want my Demo.jar to be copied.

Absolute path given in properties file is :-

***"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\google\my java"***

and script is echoing :-

***[echo] C:Documents and SettingsAdministratorDesktopgooglemy java***

Below is my edited version of build.xml and antParams.properties:-

### build.xml

```
<project default="copy">

    <property file="antParams.properties" prefix="antParams"/>

    <target name="jar" >
        <jar destfile="${antParams.jarName}"
             basedir="${antParams.binDir}"
            includes="**/*.class"

             />
    </target>

    <target name="copy" depends="jar">
            <echo>${antParams.jarDestination}</echo>
        <!-- what goes here --> 
    </target>

</project>
```

---

### antParams.properties

```
jarName=Demo.jar
binDir=bin
jarDestination=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\
```

Thanx in advance.... :-)

Comment: Try escaping your slashes:  C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double backslashes (c:\\Doc ...), or better yet, use forward slash (c:/Doc ...). Ant knows how to use forward slash in a cross-platform way, it converts it correctly to backslashes on windows.

Comment: Ant has nothing to do with that, java does that internally.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the reading of the properties file, and has nothing to do with Ant or its flexibility in recognizing file separators.

As explained in the [`java.util.Properties` documentation,](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) escape sequences start with `\`. If you want a literal backslash, you need to escape it: `\\`.

> … a non-zero even number of *2n*
>   contiguous backslashes before a line
>   terminator (or elsewhere) encodes *n* 
>   backslashes after escape processing.